# MAGENTO 2: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MageSuite' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) ... on line 7

Tags: magento2, php

I installed the module and after command

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I receive error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'MageSuite' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)  ... on line 7

> protected \MageSuite\LowestPriceLogger\Model\GetCurrentDate $getCurrentDate;

```
    <?php

namespace MageSuite\LowestPriceLogger\Model\ResourceModel;

class PriceHistoryLog extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb

{

    protected \MageSuite\LowestPriceLogger\Model\GetCurrentDate $getCurrentDate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \MageSuite\LowestPriceLogger\Model\GetCurrentDate $getCurrentDate,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);

        $this->getCurrentDate = $getCurrentDate;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('price_history_log', 'log_id');
    }

    public function getPriceHistory(array $productIds, int $websiteId = null, int $customerGroupId = null)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select();
        $select->from($this->getTableName());

        $select->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds);

        if ($websiteId !== null) {
            $select->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId);
        }

        if ($customerGroupId !== null) {
            $select->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId);
        }

        $select->where(new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('`log_date` > "%s"-INTERVAL 30 day', $this->getCurrentDate->execute())));
        $select->order('price DESC');

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    }

    public function getLowestPrices(array $productIds, int $websiteId, int $customerGroupId)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select();
        $select->from($this->getTableName());

        $select->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds);
        $select->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId);
        $select->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId);
        $select->where(new \Zend_Db_Expr('`log_date` > NOW()-INTERVAL 30 day'));

        $select->order('price ASC');
        $select->group('product_id');

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    }

    public function getLowestPrice(array $productIds, int $websiteId, int $customerGroupId)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select();
        $select->from($this->getTableName());

        $select->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds);
        $select->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId);
        $select->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId);
        $select->where(new \Zend_Db_Expr('`log_date` > NOW()-INTERVAL 30 day'));

        $select->order('price ASC');
        $select->limit(1);

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchRow($select);
    }

    public function getLastPricesPerProduct(array $productIds, int $websiteId = null, int $customerGroupId = null)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select();
        $select->from($this->getTableName());

        if ($websiteId !== null) {
            $select->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId);
        }

        if ($customerGroupId !== null) {
            $select->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId);
        }

        $select->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds);
        $select->group(['product_id', 'customer_group_id', 'website_id', 'price_type']);
        $select->order(['log_date DESC', 'log_id DESC']);

        $pricesToCompare = [];

        foreach ($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select) as $price) {
            $pricesToCompare[$price['product_id']][$price['customer_group_id']][$price['website_id']][$price['price_type']] = $price['price'];
        }

        return $pricesToCompare;
    }

    public function deleteOlderThan($retentionPeriodInDays)
    {
        $retentionPeriodInDays = (int)$retentionPeriodInDays;

        if ($retentionPeriodInDays <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        $this->getConnection()->delete(
            $this->getTableName(),
            "log_date < date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL " . $retentionPeriodInDays . " Day)"
        );
    }

    public function addPricesToLog($prices)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
            $this->getTableName(),
            $prices
        );
    }

    public function cleanTable()
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->truncateTable($this->getTableName());
    }

    protected function getTableName(): string
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->getTableName('price_history_log');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead of code at line 7

```
protected $getCurrentDate;
```

I think rest of the code was right.

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

what's your php version?

In PHP versions prior to 7.4, you cannot use type declarations for properties.

If you are using an older version of PHP, you can remove the type declaration for the property and instead add a type declaration for the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have Magento 2.3.6, PHP 7.3. Can you tell me how it should be correct? I don't know PHP so good.